# How to delete records automatically and periodically , object cases?

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, sql, apexrest

I couldn't find a way to delete records from the case object automatically periodically with code
apex please help me with this.

Comment: Schedule a batch process to delete records.

Comment: If you are the same person who previously posted a more or less identical question under multiple accounts, _stop_. If you are not the same person, please take some time to read [ask] and [help/on-topic]; you should also consider completing the Asynchronous Apex module on Trailhead, which will teach you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a batch job which you can schedule to run daily/weekly/monthly depending on your requirements.

In your batch job, you can query the case records that you want to delete, and in execute method of batch class you can perform delete DML.

Please have a look to [Salesforce Batch Job](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) and [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm).